# How do I send an ArrayList of Object though Intent?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, arraylist

I am trying to pass an array list of an object called popular people through the extras.

I have implemented parcelable interface in the object

```
public class PopularPeople implements Parcelable {

@SerializedName("popularity")
private double popularity;

@SerializedName("name")
private String name;

@SerializedName("profile_path")
private String profilePath;

@SerializedName("id")
private int id;

@SerializedName("adult")
private boolean adult;

public void setPopularity(double popularity){
    this.popularity = popularity;
}

public double getPopularity(){
    return popularity;
}

public void setName(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public void setProfilePath(String profilePath){
    this.profilePath = profilePath;
}

public String getProfilePath(){
    return profilePath;
}

public void setId(int id){
    this.id = id;
}

public int getId(){
    return id;
}

public void setAdult(boolean adult){
    this.adult = adult;
}

public boolean isAdult(){
    return adult;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return 
        "PopularPeople{" +
        "popularity = '" + popularity + '\'' +
        ",name = '" + name + '\'' + 
        ",profile_path = '" + profilePath + '\'' + 
        ",id = '" + id + '\'' + 
        ",adult = '" + adult + '\'' + 
        "}";
    }

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeDouble(this.popularity);
    dest.writeString(this.name);
    dest.writeString(this.profilePath);
    dest.writeInt(this.id);
    dest.writeByte(this.adult ? (byte) 1 : (byte) 0);
}

public PopularPeople() {
}

protected PopularPeople(Parcel in) {
    this.popularity = in.readDouble();
    this.name = in.readString();
    this.profilePath = in.readString();
    this.id = in.readInt();
    this.adult = in.readByte() != 0;
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<PopularPeople> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PopularPeople>() {
    @Override
    public PopularPeople createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new PopularPeople(source);
    }

    @Override
    public PopularPeople[] newArray(int size) {
        return new PopularPeople[size];
    }
};
}
```

Now in an activity, I am creating a new popular people object and creating a list of PopularPeople from another object Cast

```
        detailCastSeeAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // we need to convert CAST to POPULARPEOPLE. We only need name, profile path and ID.
            ArrayList<PopularPeople> popularPeople = new ArrayList<>();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            for(Cast c : cast){
                PopularPeople p = new PopularPeople();
                p.setName(c.getName());
                p.setId(c.getId());
                p.setProfilePath(c.getProfilePath());
                popularPeople.add(p);
                Timber.e("Added %s",c.getName());
            }
            Timber.e("Length before  sendin list %d",popularPeople.size());
            Intent i = new Intent(MovieDetailActivity.this, PopularPeopleActivity.class);
            b.putParcelableArrayList(AppConstants.CAST_LIST,popularPeople);
            i.putExtras(b);
            i.putExtra(AppConstants.TAG,AppConstants.MOVIE_CAST);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Now when I recieve this in the other class, the recieved array list is still empty and not populated with the list of data I sent in from the other activity.

```
           b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null){
        ArrayList<PopularPeople> peopleList = 
        b.getParcelableArrayList(AppConstants.CAST_LIST);
        tag = b != null ? b.getString(AppConstants.TAG) : null;
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error loading. Please try again..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        // return is required as we dont want to execute the code below and just want the activity to close.
        return;
    }
```

In the second activity where I recieve the intent, if I log out the size of popular people it gives out 0. How do I fix this?

Comment: Temporarily comment out `i.putExtra(AppConstants.TAG,AppConstants.MOVIE_CAST);` and see if your behavior changes. If it does, either use `putExtra()` for both or put both values into the `Bundle` for use with `putExtras()`.

Comment: Tried it. No changes.

Comment: I also tried just passing the list without the bundle. That didn't work either.

Comment: what is the result of printing this :Length before  sendin list ...

Comment: Does the `AppConstants.TAG` value make it over? If not, where are you calling `getIntent()`, and is there a chance that your activity already exists (and so you need to override `onNewIntent()`)? If `AppConstants.TAG` makes it over but `AppConstants.CAST_LIST` does not, that suggests perhaps a problem in the `Parcelable` implementation. Overall, what you are doing here is an anti-pattern. Have this cast list in some central location (e.g., a repository) that both activities can access.

Comment: Before sending, the length is 53 for one case. It varies from case to case, but it isnt zero.

Comment: Yeah the AppConstants.TAG makes it over. I am calling the getInten() in the onCreate of a new Activity. How do I do the central repository thing that you suggested? Have a utils class from which I can access it?

Comment: A `Repository` is often a singleton, for integrated cache management and so forth. See [the Architecture Components documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/guide.html#fetching_data).

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider saving the Arraylist to SharedPreferences and pass the key to it through an intent extra.

I experienced it to be the easiest to use Gson and json to write an Arraylist of Custom Objects to SharedPreferences. 
Here is a good tutorial on how to do that: https://youtu.be/jcliHGR3CHo

But if you want to use parcelable I would recommend you to watch this tutorial: https://youtu.be/WBbsvqSu0is

I hope this could help you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going with "parceable", you can go with "serializable".

**try this way may this help you**

**First you want to make**

Class Venue implements Serializable

```
 public class Venue implements Serializable { /** * */ 
 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L; }
```

**In your FirstActivity do this way**

```
 ArrayList<Venue> VenueArrayList = new ArrayList<Venue>(); 
 Intent intent = new Intent(this,secondActivity.class);      
 intent.putExtra("VenueArrayList", VenueArrayList);
```

**In your SecondActivity do this way**

```
 ArrayList<Venue> VenueArrayList; VenueArrayList = (ArrayList<Venue>)
  getIntent().getSerializableExtra( "VenueArrayList");
```